# GWT RPC security, http header, authentication and requestbuilder

Tags: java, gwt, authentication, rest, gwt-rpc

I am presuming that GWT RPC actually uses RequestBuilder.

Is there a way to extract the RequestBuilder instance used by my RPC service async requestor?

Actually, my question is, how do you extract the RequestBuilder instance to insert the authentication token as a http header? Is there a way to insert http headers into an RPC service request?

Even if I could insert a http header into the request, how then would the remote servlet be told to expect that auth token? Therefore, in fact, does GWT RPC provide a framework for secure authentication at all?

I am thinking the answer is NO, or at least not in a convenient way. Am I right?

I am coming from having used RestEasy in combination with RestyGWT over SSL, where we can insert headers anytime we wish. BTW, RestyGWT constructs its request to use RequestBuilder.

My actual motivation is comparing the security effectiveness between GWT RPC and GWT JAX-RS (RestyGWT + RestEasy). So if you, as the answerer, have an alternative detailed discourse comparing the security effectiveness of RPC with direct use of RequestBuilder or REST (rather than answering this question directly) please feel free to elaborate.

Am I right to presume that GWT RPC is not security friendly/effective and I should avoid using GWT RPC for secure authenticated requests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have your *async method* return a `Request` or a `RequestBuilder` instead of `void`. `Request` allows you to `abort()` a pending request, whereas `RequestBuilder` allows you to modify the request before its sent (if you declare the return-type as `RequestBuilder`, you're responsible for calling `send()` to actually make the request).

Alternately, you can use an [`RpcRequestBuilder`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RpcRequestBuilder.html) to customize the `RequestBuilder` for each and every call made with a specific async service proxy.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know there is no built in security solution for gwt rpc.
But If I need such authentication I would make the following steps:

1) To be able to set http headers you can make your custom request builder, as I do myself:

```
MyServiceAsync myService = GWT.create(MyService.class);
MyRequestBuilder myRequestBuilder = new MyRequestBuilder();
myRequestBuilder.addHeader("header", "value");
((ServiceDefTarget) serviceInstance).setRpcRequestBuilder(myRequestBuilder);
```

MyRequestBuilder extends RpcRequestBuilder. And inside MyRequestBuilder I override method  doFinish(RequestBuilder rb) where I put my headers.

Maybe it is not a super solution, but I haven't yet found anything better.

2) For the server side I would implement the AuthenticationFilter for checking the headers and perform server side auth functions prior calling the Servlet.

Comment: from the grave here but you are casting the variable `serviceInstance`. Should you actually be casting `myService`? Is that a typo or am I missing something?